# Static Measures in BusinessObjects 4.1

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to make a measure in SAP BusinessObjects which allways contains same value, and it does not depend on anything that's been previously selected?
This measure has to calculate following:

```
Total Costs / number of departments
```

If it's possible, please write guidelines on how to do it.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement this calculation in SQL and put that statement in a derived table, on which you would base your measure. The table would have to exist in a separate context from all other tables, as you can't link it to anything else.

It's all a bit clunky and really not what the semantic layer is designed for, but it'll probably work.

Comment: So the new table should be an island table, with only one column, which is actually the defined measure?